# How to change the drawer color of the Scaffold widget

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I change the color of the button(icon) that opens the drawer menu of the scaffold widget?

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xffc2c2c2),
  drawer: Drawer(
    ...
    child: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        DrawerHeader()


           ...
```

[image]

There is no option like iconColor or backgroundColor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `iconTheme` property of `AppBar`. For example, this is my `AppBar` code:

```
return AppBar(
  elevation: 0,
  centerTitle: true,
  brightness: DynamicTheme.of(context).brightness,
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  actions: actions == null ? [] : actions,
  title: Text(
    title,
    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.color,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
  leading: leading,
);
```

In Scaffold, there's an `appBar` property in case you didn't know. It also depends on the `brightness` property so if it's dark, the icons are going to be white, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the icon that is in the `appBar` by doing the following:

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Drawer Demo'),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black), 
        ),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/iconTheme.html